# How to resolve a problem with an error of openssl?

Tags: express, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to connect in a Login form my user but I have a problem in my cmd in back (express) and in the front in nuxt.js. 
Now its an error 404
[image]

[image]

Comment: error happens on server side and you most likely try to create a database entry with an email, that already exists in the database. the email field has unique key, so you cannot create duplicates and an error is thrown.

Comment: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line this error is link to the duplicate email ?

Comment: I guess it is just some line of code in your error stack, which leads to the error. it is in sig.js, where your app tries to sign in using Sign.sign. Afterwards it crashes during database request, because you ignore the unique key

Comment: you can catch the error using try catch and send response in catch block or by checking if email exists before

Comment: I haven't again the error with the SSL, but now when i try to connect a I have a 404

Comment: you have to send response directly or via router